# Why can't list file/directory relative to .. from a symbolic link directory (No such file or directory)?

Tags: directory, ls, symlink, cd-command

I have a `/usr/tomcat6/logs` directory linked to `/var/log/tomcat6`.

When I changed directory to `/usr/tomcat6/logs` and try to `ls` files using a relative pathname `../conf/Catalina/localhost`, a **No such file or directory** error occurs. However, `cd ../conf/Catalina/localhost` works.

See the following:

```
[root@fedora ~]# ll /usr/tomcat*
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 21 Jun 17 15:00 /usr/tomcat6 -> apache-tomcat-6.0.32/
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 21 Jun 17 13:03 /usr/tomcat7 -> apache-tomcat-7.0.16/
[root@fedora ~]# cd /usr/tomcat6
[root@fedora tomcat6]# ll logs
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 16 Jun 17 14:51 logs -> /var/log/tomcat6
[root@fedora tomcat6]# cd logs
[root@fedora logs]# cd ../conf/Catalina/localhost
[root@fedora localhost]# pwd
/usr/tomcat6/conf/Catalina/localhost
[root@fedora localhost]# cd /usr/tomcat6/logs
[root@fedora logs]# ll ../conf/Catalina/localhost
ls: cannot access ../conf/Catalina/localhost: No such file or directory
```

How could this happened? Is it a bug or special behaviour of symbolic link?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is special behavior of `bash`'s `cd` builtin; the relative file behavior is the natural one.  Once you follow a symbolic link, you are in the actual path of the target and the original path information is lost; but if you use `bash` or `zsh` to `cd` there then the shell remembers the original path and uses it in future relative `cd` commands.  But not in relative filename references, because `bash` doesn't actually know if you intended a filename or something else.

If you look at the `cd` documentation in `bash`, you'll see there are `-L` and `-P` options which tell it whether to use "logical" (remembering the original path) or "physical" (using the filesystem's idea) paths.

If you need to have the "logical" behavior at all times, you need to use a `--bind` mount (on Linux; Solaris and other OSes call it "loopback" or other things) instead of a symlink.

Comment: can I understand it like this: in bash, only `cd` command is taken care of about it's argument, others are not been taken care of (`ls ../conf` failed, `[[ -e ../conf ]]` failed, `test -e ../conf`, etc ...)?

Comment: `cd` and the related `pushd`.