# How to explain a weird cd behavior on macOS?

Tags: macos, cd-command

My system is macOS 13.2.1, the shell is oh-my-zsh (same behavior on bash). I found a weird behavior on `cd` command. It changes the current directory to a wrong one. This is not caused by the soft link, because there is no directory in the right path.

```
!w /Library/TeX/texbin ........................................................................................................... 14:56:24
> cd ../../texmf-dist

!w /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist ............................................................................................ 14:56:40
> cd -               
/Library/TeX/texbin

!w /Library/TeX/texbin ........................................................................................................... 14:56:42
> cd ../../          

!w /Library ...................................................................................................................... 14:56:51
> cd texmf-dist      
cd: no such file or directory: texmf-dist
```

Comment: This looks like you are accessing a directory via a symbolic link. It is likely that `/Library/TeX` is a symbolic link to `/usr/local/texlive/2021`, but as you don't show the contents of the directories, it's hard to tell exactly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of the following question: [Why can't list file/directory relative to .. from a symbolic link directory (No such file or directory)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/15284)

Comment: Thanks! Your advice make sense. I've checked that the symbolic link is `/Library/TeX/texbin -> /usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/universal-darwin`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned `/Library/TeX` is a symbolic link to `/usr/local/texlive/2021/universal-darwin/`, and that causes the ambiguity.

When you're in `/Library/TeX/texbin` (really `/usr/local/texlive/2021/universal-darwin/texbin`) and run `cd ../..`, the shell looks to see if `/Library/texmf-dist` exists, that is, it remembers the path with the link you used to go there, and removes one path element for each `..`, in effect undoing the step taken through the link. You end up in `/Library`. And `/Library/texmf-dist` doesn't exist so the final `cd` doesn't work.

Similarly with `cd ../../texmf-dist` it would try to go to `/Library/texmf-dist` but that doesn't exist. But here, it checks if that path makes sense in the actual location you're in, without remembering the symlink. It does, and you end up in `/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist`. Note how the path changed completely as a consequence of the shell having to forget the path via the symlink.

If you go back to `/Library/TeX/texbin` and run `cd -P ../..` instead, it uses the "physical" path, again forgetting the symbolic link, and you end up in `/usr/local/texlive/2021`, where `cd texmf-dist` would again work normally.

The structure looks like this, and the difference comes from which path up is chosen when going to `..` from `universal-darwin` (I assume none of the other dirs are symlinks):

```
/Library -> Tex - - - -(symlink)- - +
                                    v
/usr -> local -> texlive -> 2021 -> universal-darwin -> texbin
                              |
                              +---> texfmt-dist
```

The way the shell remembers the symlink you used is a usability feature, in many cases it means you don't need to remember where something actually is, when you can just make a symlink with a nicer name and go through that. It's easier to remember `~/thingy` rather than `/net/fileserver1/disk02/dir/thingy` or whatever.

But it means the directory tree isn't a *tree* any more, and "up" turns ambiguous.

Hence, it can break down when going up "past" the symlink target. In particular programs started from the shell won't know what the shell remembers about the symlinks and they'll use the "physical" parent directory, always. E.g. in your case, with `/Library/TeX` being a symlink, running `ls ..` there should show a different listing than `cd ..; ls`.